# Javascript search in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps

I'Ve got a problem with the $.inArray function from JQuery (I also tried indexOf)

My Code:

```
var branches = circles[i].branches;
var counter = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < branches.length; j++) {

   var circle_branch = branches[j];
   var index = $.inArray( circle_branch, activeBranchSettings);
   if (index == -1)counter++;                   
}
if(counter == 0) circles[i].setMap(map);
```

So I'm working with the Google Maps API and I've a control panel with some categories (branches) where I toggle the Markers. Each circle (Marker) can have multiple branches and those ID's are attached to each circle. So I loop through the branches and want to find that ID in an other array (activeBranchSettings), every time there wasn't a match I increase a counter. If the counter is 0 in the end I toggle the circle on. So this tells which Markers should NOT be shown and which should.

Whether it'S the perfect way to solve it or not, the problem is that

```
  var index = $.inArray( circle_branch, activeBranchSettings);
```

return -1 everytime!
The value IS at that point in the array and I tried to convert "circle_branch" into a string with .toString(), but still no change, Any ideas?

Comment: what the hellis `activeBranchSettings` variable? where it comes from?

Comment: We need to know examples of what the `circle_branch` variable can be and also what can be in the `activeBranchSettings` array.

Comment: `circle_branch` is an int and `activeBranchSettings` is an array with ints

Comment: Have you tried putting some of your data in Bernhard's answer? Can you show us the data?

Comment: If `$.inArray()` returns -1 then you can be sure that the target value is not in the array. I expect your data is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

These testcase is working well.
So maybe a compare of the datatype (typeof(variable)) would be a step to find the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = new Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    var look = new Array('d', 'b');

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    alert($.inArray( arr[i], look));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per jQuery documentation inArray has the following syntax.

```
jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )
```

Means `value` should come firt and `array` should come second. It's not quite clear form your example what is `activeBranchSettings` is it an array or searchable value?

Comment: `activeBranchSettings` is an array yes, if I type "5" in the value parameter it returns the correct index, so I don't know what's wrong with `circle_branch`